# POST data received in node.js server returned to client as undefined

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm starting to learn node.js. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org) and I've run into a problem where some POST data is received properly but when it's returned to the client, it becomes "undefined".

Here's the code for grabbing the POST data (this is Coffeescript btw):

```
postData = ""
request.setEncoding "utf8"
request.addListener "data", (postDataChunk) ->
  postData += postDataChunk
  console.log "Received POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk + "'."

request.addListener "end", ->
  console.log "postData at end: " + postData
  POST = qs.parse postData
  console.log POST

route handle, pathname, response, POST.text
```

The POST text is sent to a routing function along with the response object. The code there is:

```
upload = (response, postData) ->
  console.log "Request handler 'upload' was called"
  console.log "post data in upload: " + postData
  response.writeHead 200, "Content-Type": "text/plain"
  response.end "You sent: " + postData
```

In the console output, PostData is set correctly but when I view the output in the browser it'll always say "You sent: undefined"

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at POST.text inside the `end` callback.  Instead of `console.log POST`, do `console.dir POST` and see if the POST object has a property named `text` defined.  My guess is it does not.  If not, log the raw postData string and see if it is not what you expect.